# Why Redis SortedSet uses Skip List instead of Balanced Tree?

Tags: data-structures, redis, sortedset, skip-lists

The Redis document said as below :

> ZSETs are ordered sets using two data structures to hold the same elements
>    in order to get O(log(N)) INSERT and REMOVE operations into a sorted
>    data structure.
>
> The elements are added to a hash table mapping Redis objects to
>   scores.  At the same time the elements are added to a skip list
>   mapping scores  to Redis objects (so objects are sorted by scores in
>   this "view").

I can not understand very much. Could someone give me a detailed explanation?

Comment: Find what pros/cons each of these days structures offer and maybe you'll be able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antirez said, see in https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1171423

There are a few reasons:

- They are not very memory intensive. It's up to you basically. Changing parameters about the probability of a node to have a given number of levels will make then less memory intensive than btrees.
- A sorted set is often target of many ZRANGE or ZREVRANGE operations, that is, traversing the skip list as a linked list. With this operation the cache locality of skip lists is at least as good as with other kind of balanced trees.
- They are simpler to implement, debug, and so forth. For instance thanks to the skip list simplicity I received a patch (already in Redis master) with augmented skip lists implementing ZRANK in O(log(N)). It required little changes to the code.

About the Append Only durability & speed, I don't think it is a good idea to optimize Redis at cost of more code and more complexity for a use case that IMHO should be rare for the Redis target (fsync() at every command). Almost no one is using this feature even with ACID SQL databases, as the performance hint is big anyway.

About threads: our experience shows that Redis is mostly I/O bound. I'm using threads to serve things from Virtual Memory. The long term solution to exploit all the cores, assuming your link is so fast that you can saturate a single core, is running multiple instances of Redis (no locks, almost fully scalable linearly with number of cores), and using the "Redis Cluster" solution that I plan to develop in the future.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think I got the idea of what the Redis documents says. Redis ordered set maintain the order of elements by the the element's score specified by user. But when user using some Redis Zset APIs, it only gives element args. For example:

```
ZREM key member [member ...]
ZINCRBY key increment member
...
```

redis need to know what value is about this member (element), so it uses hash table maintaining a mapping, just like the documents said:

> The elements are added to a hash table mapping Redis objects to
>   scores.

when it receives a member, it finds its value through the hash table, and then manipulate the operation on the skip list to maintain the order of set. redis uses two data structure to maintain a double mapping to satisfy the need of the different API.

I read the papers by William Pugh **Skip Lists: A Probabilistic
 Alternative to Balanced Trees**, and found the skip list is very elegant and easier to implement than rotating.

Also, I think the general binary balanced tree is able to do this work at the same time cost. I case I've missed something, please point that out.

Comment: You missed the point that retrieving the nth item in a skip list is O(log(n)) while it is O(n) in a balanced tree. It is very useful for ZRANK or ZRANGE commands.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think if we maintain a value children_count of each node in balanced tree, we could get the nth item in O(log(n)) in bt

Comment: @DidierSpezia why is receiving the n'th item a O(n) operation in a balanced tree? Couldn't the tree be designed like an Order Statistic Tree (each node knows the size of its left and right subtree) so that finding the n'th item becomes O(logn)?

Comment: @DidierSpezia and also ZREVRANGE is not implement easily in rb tr