# Redis - Sorted Set ZRANGE performance

Tags: redis

I am really confused with redis sorted set.

Lets say I have N number of items in the sorted set. I assumed whenever I add an item, it will be sorted in the set.

If I need the lowest score item, I have to use this.

```
ZRANGE myitem 0 0
```

But why is the performance is `O(log(N)`). Should it not be `O(1)` if it is already sorted & to get the lowest score item?

https://redis.io/commands/zrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-sorted-sets), Redis uses a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) to implement sorted sets. Skip lists have a lookup time of O(log n).

There are other answers here that go into more detail on the use of this data structure, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115047/why-redis-sortedset-uses-skip-list-instead-of-balanced-tree) for example.